# Setting a binary value for multiple condiitons in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data that has sleeping and waking time of each person as below.

| id | current_time | asleep | wokeup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 00:01 | 23:10 | 6:15 |
| 25 | 02:01 | 23:10 | 6:15 |
| 25 | 06:55 | 23:10 | 6:15 |
| 18 | 22:03 | 00:10 | 6:15 |
| 18 | 23:33 | 00:10 | 6:15 |
| 18 | 00:33 | 00:10 | 6:15 |

I would like to have a new column named  **wake**. This column shoud be binary. If the current_time is between asleep and woketime, then wake value should be 0, otherwise 1. I expect to have a table like below.

| id | current_time | asleep | wokeup | wake |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 00:01 | 23:10 | 6:15 | 0 |
| 25 | 02:01 | 23:10 | 6:15 | 0 |
| 25 | 06:55 | 23:10 | 6:15 | 1 |
| 18 | 22:03 | 00:10 | 6:15 | 1 |
| 18 | 23:33 | 00:10 | 6:15 | 1 |
| 18 | 00:33 | 00:10 | 6:15 | 0 |

My dataset is called df_clean2.

I attempted to solve it like below. Firstly (1), I assigned 1 value in wake column for all rows. Then (2), I wrote a boolean to change the column value of **wake** to 1 for given conditions

```
#(1)
df_clean2['wake'] =  0

#(2)
df_clean2['wake'] = np.where(((df_clean2.time <  df_clean2.asleep) | (df_clean2.time > df_clean2.wokeup)), df_clean2.wake, 1)
```

But, this code does not change the wake column value  for id 25 and current_time 06:55, I get wake value of 0 for my code. I also tried to put and condiiton instead of or, but also does not work. Can you help me to modify my code so that I have my output as expcted?

Comment: you re  comparing `strings` so you need to convert your columns to  `current_time` `asleep` and `wokeup` to `time` type

Comment: I just converted them to time using pd.to_datetime, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky as the comparison is circular. You need to compare the current time to each bound but also the bounds themselves:

```
curr = pd.to_timedelta(df['current_time']+':00')
s = pd.to_timedelta(df['asleep']+':00')
w = pd.to_timedelta(df['wokeup']+':00')

df['wake'] = ((curr.ge(s)==curr.ge(w))==s.le(w)).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   id current_time asleep wokeup  wake
0  25        00:01  23:10   6:15     0
1  25        02:01  23:10   6:15     0
2  25        06:55  23:10   6:15     1
3  18        22:03  00:10   6:15     1
4  18        23:33  00:10   6:15     1
5  18        00:33  00:10   6:15     0
```